# Calling Codeigniter controller method not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm starting to develop with CI, I'm trying to call another controller that I call `LOGIN` but it gets me the error "NOT FOUND", whereas if I put my controller in default_controller, it works, I already have read the other forum about this problem but it does not solve my case,

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        redirect("/welcome/index");
        $this->load->view("login");
    }

}
```

Comment: show us your folder structure. Better if you could add a snap

Comment: There are many reasons why this could be happening. Right now, we don't have enough information to diagnose the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions
1.  Please add .htaccess to the codigniter

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2. Can create a routing for login controller then you can call directly
3. Add $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; in config.php

Answer (score 0):

**Solution -1**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

        public function index() {
            redirect("index.php/welcome/index");
            $this->load->view("login");
        }

    }
```

**Solution-2**

**application/config/config.php** file you not remove index.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

change it

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and using .htaccess index.php remove.

[Reference link: index.php from URL](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/)